# Calibri font in birt designer on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, fonts, birt

I am developing BIRT report on Ubuntu environment, I see that, there is no font type called "Calibri" in Property Editor for an text/label element.

What should i do to have Calibri font type in my BIRT designer?

BIRT version - 4.4.1

Comment: I have both Calibri and Calibri Light in my BIRT 4.2, what version of BIRT are you running and where are you trying to use the font?

Comment: I am trying to set font "Calibri" for a text and a label element.And I am working on Ubuntu environment.